# Tableau Calculated field going off

Tags: tableau-desktop

Below is the if else statement I am using.

```
IF ([Days]<='0' or [Days]='none') THEN '0'
ELSEIF [Days]>'0' or [Days]<='273.5' THEN '182'
ELSEIF [Days]>'273.5' or [Days]<='548' THEN '365'
ELSEIF [Days]>'548' or [Days]<='913' THEN '730'
ELSEIF [Days]>'913' or [Days]<='1460' THEN '1095'
ELSE '1825' 
END
```

However, I am seeing few rows going off. First column is number of days, second and third columns are same (Calculated field)

[image]

Comment: You can simplify/clarify your calculation by removing all the tests involving a ">". They are redundant because of the earlier tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings instead of integers. String comparison is based on alphabetical order. That explains why `'30' > '273.5'` even though `30 < 273.5` A pair of quotation marks makes a significant difference.

Change the data type for [Days] to a whole number, and then remove the quotes in your calculated field so that you are comparing numbers instead of strings.

Also, you can simplify/clarify your calculation by removing all the tests involving a ">". They are redundant because of the earlier tests - as long as you test in increasing order. Simple is usually better.

Comment: I did convert the Days field into INT, but there is a value in the Days column as "None'.

I used the below calculation to tackle the None value but when I pull this column in the worksheet, it gives me "Bad double value: None"

if [Days] = "None" Then 0
else INT([Days])

Comment: Just change the data type of the original field to number (whole) by right clicking on the field in the data pane (left margin). Values that cannot be converted to ints will be treated as null values. Nulls are ignored by aggregate functions and you can test for them explicitly with ISNULL() . Note, you’ll want to test ISNULL first in your calc to get the right behavior